# Exception: invalid-credential when register(Flutter and Firebase)

Tags: flutter, firebase

(Flutter and Firebase)
i'm just following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xU5WH2kEc0&t=1525s. 25:20 -> when i register and input email, pw, confirmpw, the exception occurred.

The exception occurred when input email, pw, and confirmpw correctly.

Expect result: register new email and pw

Comment: Have you accepted the authentication service to accept email/password in Firebase console? This could help https://flutterjunction.com/how-to-perform-secure-authentication-with-firebase-bloc-in-flutter

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)